# How do you overlap columns in bootstrap3 on the same row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve this effect in bootstrap 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZRRC.png

Bootstrap uses 12 columns by default. If all column-widths in the current row adds up to more than 12, the overflowing column(s) ends up beneath on the "next row".

The divs look like this at the moment:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     ...[left window]
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-1">
     ...[middle, bigger window]
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-2">
     ...[right window]
  </div>
</div>
```

This is 14 columns. The middle window correctly overlaps the left one. But the right window ends up **below** the left one, but two columns to the left.

Is there any way to prevent this behaviour and keeping all col-md-* on the same line, even though there are more than 12 (14 in this case)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it out of the box with bootstrap as far as I know. Instead, use a class in the last column and add a negative margin.

Here an example with your HTML and bootstrap3:
http://cdpn.io/bAKfj

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks man :) That's a really easy solution

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there is no way to get more than 12 columns/spans in one row.
You can however create rows inside the columns to get access to even more columns like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="row">
          //12 columns here
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="row">
          //12 columns here
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This way they are still in "one" row. Uncertain whether it will work or not with your effect though.